# The system cannot find the path specified: ' '

Tags: python, path

I am trying to split my image data set into train test and val. It has already created the train, test and val folders, but its empty as I keep encountering an error. This is the code I am trying to run on jupyter notebook, I have imported the required libraries like os, numoy, shutil, random:

```
# # Creating Train / Val / Test folders 

root_dir = 'Desktop/sem_8_project/brain/brain_tumor_dataset/' # data root path
classes_dir = ['no', 'yes'] #total labels

val_ratio = 0.15
test_ratio = 0.05

for cls in classes_dir:
    os.makedirs(root_dir +'train/' + cls)
    os.makedirs(root_dir +'val/' + cls)
    os.makedirs(root_dir +'test/' + cls)

for cls in classes_dir:
    src = root_dir + cls # Folder to copy images from

    allFileNames = os.listdir(src)
    np.random.shuffle(allFileNames)
    train_FileNames, val_FileNames, test_FileNames = np.split(np.array(allFileNames),
```

and this is the error it shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-e2cee9006649> in <module>
      3     src = root_dir + cls # Folder to copy images from
      4 
----> 5     allFileNames = os.listdir(src)
      6     np.random.shuffle(allFileNames)
      7     train_FileNames, val_FileNames, test_FileNames = np.split(np.array(allFileNames),

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Desktop/sem_8_project/brain/brain_tumor_dataset/no'
```

Comment: Okay, so it's telling you quite clearly, that it can't find a file at `Desktop/sem_8_project/brain/brain_tumor_dataset/no`. Is that where you expected it to look for the file? If so, why do you expect it to find a file at that location? For that matter, why do you expect it to find the `Desktop` folder? Do you understand what a *current working directory* is? Do you know what the current working directory was for your program when you ran it? Do you know how to check?

Comment: Are you running inside the `Desktop` folder?

Comment: @thethiny yes, the file is in desktop

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `Desktop/sem_8_project/brain/brain_tumor_dataset/no` this folder has 98 images which I want want to split 3 ways. My current directory says `\\Users\\gayat\\Desktop`

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a path-related question, and it has actually nothing to do with `deep-learning` or `image-processing` (tags removed). Also, please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), and it should *not* be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out). SO does not work by simply posting the whole of our code here as-is, please see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @desertnaut noted. Thank you. I joined today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last 4 lines of code instead of using: `allFileNames = os.listdir(src)` I used:

```
    allFileNames = []
    for filename in os.listdir(src):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(src,filename))
        if img is not None: 
            allFileNames.append(img)
```

This worked for me and the directory error got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message stated, python can not find the directory you provided. You can not access to Desktop/ directly, but have to specify address of it.
Try this code as the link to desktop.

```
os.path.join(os.environ['HOMEPATH'], 'Desktop')
```

Comment: Did you tried `root_dir = os.path.join(os.environ['HOMEPATH'], 'Desktop', 'sem_8_project', 'brain', 'brain_tumor_dataset')` ?

Comment: Just tried it and this is the error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\Users\\gayat\\Desktop\\sem_8_project\\brain\\brain_tumor_datasetno` it says **datasetno** now and the earlier error said **dataset/no**

Comment: You should use `os.path.join` to join folder path. Instead of using `root_dir + 'no'`, you should use `os.path.join(root_dir, 'no') `to create path to `no` folder, it help avoid error when constructing path. (The same for other path construction)